# Render coffee partial in slim template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, slim-lang

This is what I did, working in development, fails in production.

```
javascript:
  #{ raw render 'my_partial.js' }
```

My partial is called `my_partial.js.coffee`.

This also works in development:

```
javascript:
  #{ raw render 'my_partial.js', handlers: [:coffee]}
```

Is there any other way like:

```
coffee:
  #{ render 'my_partial' }
```

I mean, what is the shortest form to include a coffee partial inside an slim template? and why the first way fails in production, saying:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial my_partial 
with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim]}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use any filter at all.

Your slim file should just use

```
= render 'my_partial'
```

and your partial should contain

```
coffee:
  # coffee script here
```

Comment: I would want to have my_partial.js.coffee to have colors in file.

Comment: Depends; if your partial is just coffeescript, it should probably just be a .coffee file. If that's the case, then you should probably move it out of your views altogether and put it in your assets directory.

Comment: hmm, that's the first thing I had to do, I mean to move that to assets. I just not sure about sending the large file, but seems that's very common, you have some link to read how to serve assets in an organised way?